# is `onPageFinished` is called after `onReceivedError` in anyway?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have this code:

```
private final class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap  favicon) {
        url = "localhost:999";
        mIsLoaded = false;
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        mIsLoaded = true;
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
        mIsLoaded = false;
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

}
```

What is the relation and order of the overridden events

in case of success?

in case of failure?

MyWebClient should set a dialog content

but i want it to hide the dialog if my error code is not 0.

Should I do a "return" in `onReceivedError` only or `onPageFinished` is called anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPageFinished` tells you that the WebView has stopped loading. `onReceivedError` tells you there was an error. They're not "success" and "failure" callbacks which is why you'll get both in case of an error.

Also, the [callback implementations in WebViewClient](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClient.java) usually don't do anything useful, so it makes no difference wither you're calling `super.onReceivedError` or not. There is no way to "do a return" in `onReceivedError`. If you want to display something else in case of an error then call `view.loadUrl(...)` from `onReceivedError`.

Comment: btw why do i see my `onPageStarted` called twice: before and after the `onReceivedError` ?

Comment: @EladBenda: that's surprising, which version of Android are you testing on? My guess would be the WebView is generating callbacks for the navigation to the error page.